# jQuery copy height of the closest div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jQuery script (below) to get a height of one div and apply it to the one next to it. It works absolutely fine, but it gets wrong if I have another row with the same .app-screenshot class inside, which has a different height.

How can I make **.app-screenshot-description** class get the height only of the closest **.app-screenshot** class height?

```js
function getImgHeight() {
    var divHeight = $('.app-screenshot').height(); 
    $('.app-screenshot-description').css('height', divHeight+'px');
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="app-screenshot">This divs height is 690px</div>
<div class="app-screenshot-description">Second div</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="app-screenshot">This divs height is 540px</div>
<div class="app-screenshot-description">Second div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/closest/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your html structure is following this pattern

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="app-screenshot"></div>
 <div class="app-screenshot-description"></div>
</div>
```

You can try something like this.

```
$('.row').each(function(){
     var divHeight = $(this).find('.app-screenshot').height(); 
    $(this).find('.app-screenshot-description').css('height', divHeight+'px');
});
```

You can use closest as well as mentioned in the comment, but if heights are different for each div, you still need to loop over them using each

Answer (score 0):

Search for the divs that are with common Y coordinate:

```
function getImgHeight() {
$('.app-screenshot').each(function(){
    var divHeight = $(this).height();
    var divPosition = $(this).offset().top;
    $('.app-screenshot-description').each(function(){
        if($(this).offset().top == divPosition)
        {
            /*console.log($(this).offset().top);*/
            $(this).css('height', divHeight+'px');
        }
    });
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say when your function is supposed to run, but if you loop over the rows, it can work:

```js
$(".row").each(function(index, row){
  $(row).find(".app-screenshot-description").css("height", $(row).find(".app-screenshot").css("height"));
});
```

```css
.row { border:1px solid black;}

.row > div { border:1px dashed red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="app-screenshot" style="height:100px">This divs height is 100px</div>
  <div class="app-screenshot-description">Second div</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="app-screenshot" style="height:25px">This divs height is 25px</div>
  <div class="app-screenshot-description">Second div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

While you have, as I write this answer, already accepted another answer to your question, I thought I'd take a moment to offer a further answer, which hopefully provides some further alternatives that may may be of use to you. Particularly since the solutions I offer here require no JavaScript to use (although I do use jQuery to demonstrate the functionality of those solutions).

There are three obvious approaches to take that would allow your desired functionality in pure CSS; in this answer I'll go through those options in order of (personal) preference.

#### 1: flexbox.

This approach takes advantage of the fact that flexbox sizes its child items to be the same cross-axis dimension (if the contents are arranged in a row then the cross-axis dimension would be the height, and if arranged in a column the cross-axis dimension would be width).

```js
// This is purely to demonstrate that both elements take
// the same height (that of the 'tallest' sibling.

// binding the anonymous function of the on() method as
// the event-handler for the 'click' event:
$('#resizeHeight').on('click', function() {

  // selecting all elements matching the selector,
  // and using the css() method's anonymous function
  // to style each '.app-screenshot' element
  // independently:
  $('.app-screenshot').css('height', function() {

    // generating a random height up to a maximum of 500px:
    let newHeight = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);

    // setting the height of the current element:
    this.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
    // setting the text of the current element:
    this.textContent = newHeight;
  });
// triggering the click event on page-load in order
// the elements have a randomly-assigned size on
// page-load:
}).click();
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 3em;
}

#control {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 2.5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.row {
  /* setting the display to use the
     flexbox layout: */
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.row>div {
  /* setting the flex-grow and flex-shrink
     to be 1, and the flex-basis to be auto: */
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

/* Everything below is either for aesthetics
   or simple visibility: */
.app-screenshot {
  background-color: fuchsia;
}

.app-screenshot-description {
  background-color: silver;
}

.app-screenshot::before {
  content: "This element's height is: ";
}

.app-screenshot::after {
  content: 'px.';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="control">
  <button id="resizeHeight">Randomise height of '.app-screenshot' elements</button>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="app-screenshot"></div>
  <div class="app-screenshot-description">Second div</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="app-screenshot"></div>
  <div class="app-screenshot-description">Second div</div>
</div>
```

#### 2. CSS grids.

```js
// This is purely to demonstrate that both elements take
// the same height (that of the 'tallest' sibling.

// binding the anonymous function of the on() method as
// the event-handler for the 'click' event:
$('#resizeHeight').on('click', function() {

  // selecting all elements matching the selector,
  // and using the css() method's anonymous function
  // to style each '.app-screenshot' element
  // independently:
  $('.app-screenshot').css('height', function() {

    // generating a random height up to a maximum of 500px:
    let newHeight = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);

    // setting the height of the current element:
    this.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
    // setting the text of the current element:
    this.textContent = newHeight;
  });
  // triggering the click event on page-load in order
  // the elements have a randomly-assigned size on
  // page-load:
}).click();
```

```css
body {
  /* Setting the display to use CSS grid layout: */
  display: grid;

  /* specifying the number of rows, to:
     row 1: 3em high,
     row 2: min-content,
     row 3: min-content.
     'min-content' directs the row to be the
     smallest practicable size that will still
     fully contain the content of the elements
     in that row, and because the elements take
     up the whole of the allocated space those
     elements are of equal height: */
  grid-template-rows: 3em min-content min-content;
}

.row {
  /* setting the display of the .row elements
     to also use grid layout: */
  display: grid;

  /* setting both columns to be 1 fractional unit
     therefore both columns will be the same size;
     this can, of course, be adjusted to taste
     using any valid CSS grid length unit: */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.app-screenshot {
  /* Assigning the .app-screenshot element(s) to
     be positioned in the first column of its
     parent: */
  grid-column: 1;
  background-color: fuchsia;
}

.app-screenshot-description {
  /* Assigning the .app-screenshot-description
     element(s) to be positioned in the second
     column of its parent: */
  grid-column: 2;
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="control">
  <button id="resizeHeight">Randomise height of '.app-screenshot' elements</button>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="app-screenshot"></div>
  <div class="app-screenshot-description">Second div</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="app-screenshot"></div>
  <div class="app-screenshot-description">Second div</div>
</div>
```

#### 3. CSS tables.

Ideally this would not be used since – and this is a purely personal opinion – it feels too close to using a `<table>` element for layout reasons, and while we're not using a `<table>` element we are using this for, purely, layout reasons. Which still feels dirty to me. It is, though, an option that could be used.

While I would tend to avoid this solution it does have the potential advantage of simplicity, despite the associated 'smell,' and takes advantage of a table-cell's parent table-row being defined by the 'tallest' of its descendants.

```js
// This is purely to demonstrate that both elements take
// the same height (that of the 'tallest' sibling.

// binding the anonymous function of the on() method as
// the event-handler for the 'click' event:
$('#resizeHeight').on('click', function() {

  // selecting all elements matching the selector,
  // and using the css() method's anonymous function
  // to style each '.app-screenshot' element
  // independently:
  $('.app-screenshot').css('height', function() {

    // generating a random height up to a maximum of 500px:
    let newHeight = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);

    // setting the height of the current element:
    this.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
    // setting the text of the current element:
    this.textContent = newHeight;
  });
  // triggering the click event on page-load in order
  // the elements have a randomly-assigned size on
  // page-load:
}).click();
```

```css
.row {
  /* forcing the '.row' element(s) to display
     as a table-row: */
  display: table-row;
}

.app-screenshot,
.app-screenshot-description {
  /* forcing the selected elements to display
     as table-cells: */
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50vw;
  /* emulating the margin-bottom of previous
     demos in this answer: */
  border-bottom: 1em solid #fff;
}

.app-screenshot {
  background-color: fuchsia;
}

.app-screenshot-description {
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="control">
  <button id="resizeHeight">Randomise height of '.app-screenshot' elements</button>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="app-screenshot"></div>
  <div class="app-screenshot-description">Second div</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="app-screenshot"></div>
  <div class="app-screenshot-description">Second div</div>
</div>
```

Please note that while I've used jQuery to allow the `.app-screenshot` elements to be resized neither that jQuery, nor any JavaSCript at all, is necessary to implement these posted solutions, it was used purely to demonstrate the functionality of the solutions.